# Hochschild homology of a free commutative algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

Let $V$ be a graded vector space over $k$. Let $Com(V)$ be the free commutative algebra over V. Let $HH_*(-,k)$ be the Hochschild homology with coefficients in $k$ functor.

My questions are :
$$
HH_*(Com(V),k) \cong \Lambda^*(V) ?
$$

Is the Hochschild-Kostant-Rosenberg theorem of any use here?

Comment: This is done in detail in Loday's book on cyclic homology, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Using the Künneth formula, you can reduce this to the casee where $V$ is one-dimensional, and mak a direct computation in that case. (If your $V$ may be infinite-dimensional, you need to use the fact that homology commutes with direct limits, too)

Comment: Ok! thank you for the reference, I will check it as soon as possible.